# preferences disappeared

Tags: preferences

I remember there was a cog in the menu in the uuper right corner of the screen

The cog opened the app for editing the preferences

Now the cog is gone and I can't open the preferences anymore

What have I done ?

How can I fix this ?

```
:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? When "the cog" was gone?

Comment: of course I'm using Ubuntu

19.10

I don't know when, I didn't realize !

Comment: I think I attached a picture to thsi question but I can't find it

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is EoL and off-topic.

Comment: look, it's the most recent release, I don't remember the exact number by raw memory !

I can't even check exactly because my preferences app is nowhere around !

Comment: I checked on the ubuntu site

it's 20.10 !|

Comment: you could have asked me if I was sure before closing my question

Comment: Press the left-side "Windows" key. That will give you an "overlay" (called the Activities-overlay) with a small text-field near the center top. Type "settings". The settings app's icon will be offered to you to click on.

Comment: @Levente all the offeredoptions are not installed, they are into "Software", the app

Comment: @Pilot6 ehm....

Comment: @user1632812 if you can open a terminal, run `lsb_release -a` and add the output to the question, please.

Comment: @muru done. Thanks

Comment: One more suggestion: look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` (and older log files in that folder) to see which packages you have removed recently.

Comment: @muru thank you very much. I removed mysql* ¯\_(ツ)_/¯